# Trouble defining an environment variable on Cygwin

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, environment-variables, vi

I'm using the Cygwin 64-bit installation on my Windows 7 machine.  In my `~/.bash_profile`, I set

```
export JBOSS_HOME=/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/wildfly-10.0.0.CR2/
```

However, when I attempt to open a file using the $JBOSS_HOME environment variable,

```
$ vi $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
```

The file doesn't open properly and instead attempts to open two files in vi, one of which is

```
"/cygdrive/c/Program" [New File]
```

What is the proper way to define my environment variable so that I can use it when opening it again in vi?

Answer (score 2):

Use double-quotes to send the entire string as one parameter.

```
$ vi "$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml"
```